# Approval workflow: "Assigned to" field gets different user name in list and autogenerated e-mail

Tags: workflow, active-directory, user-profile-service

I've added an Approval workflow on my development server and manually copied the workflow in the production environment (since no efficient deployment tool for configured workflows seems to exist). However, it appears that the user name for the selected approvers becomes "DOMAINNAME\username" on the development machine, whereas it is just "username" on the prouction machine. For some users on the production machine, the name becomes the full name of the user.

My problem is, these names are used as the filter value for the workflow tasks list, where the filter value (username) is added to the automated e-mails that are sent out to approvers. Even though the names represent the same user, differences in spelling will cause list filtering to fail. In some cases, the e-mail system seems to become confused and uses a different name convention in the e-mail link than the one that's used in the workflow task list, leading to broken list filtering for end-users which have low computer skills.

I get the impression that differences in naming are sometimes related to an incorrectly configured User Profile Service Application. Does anyone know how to solve this specific issue or, in general, how to ensure that user names are consistently displayed?